# Laravel : How do I insert the first user in the database

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-seeding

I am using Laravel (4.2)

I am working on a project with an authentication system. I need to insert a first user into my users table. I would like to do that directly with a sql command (insert into users....). Because this first user can't be created with the traditional laravel methods.

This first user will be identified with the  auth::attempts method, after being inserted into the table.

How do I insert this user into mysql table?

something like?

```
insert into  users (login, password) values ('admin', 'crypted password which can be later identified with laravel')
```

Comment: Do you want to execute th `SQL` from within `Laravel`? If not why you are not executing that `SQL` from `phpMyAdmin` or `MySql-console`.

Comment: Laravel works with routes, controllers and models I suppose you already have set those in place before you are going to query your database

Comment: Franco : no I have not yet all these requirements. For the other users of course I will have. But for the 1st one, how to create it into the database ?

Answer (score 82):

I'm doing it this way:

creating seeder with artisan:

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder
```

then you open the file and you enter users:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'User1',
            'email' => 'user1@email.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        ]);
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => 'user2',
            'email' => 'user2@email.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('password'),
        ]);
    }
}
```

If you want to generate random list of users, you can use factories:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        factory(App\User::class, 50)->create();
        /* or you can add also another table that is dependent on user_id:*/
       /*factory(App\User::class, 50)->create()->each(function($u) {
            $userId = $u->id;
            DB::table('posts')->insert([
                'body' => str_random(100),
                'user_id' => $userId,
            ]);
        });*/
    }
}
```

Then in the file app/database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php uncomment or add in run function a line:

```
$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
```

it will look like this:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

At the end you run:

```
php artisan db:seed
```

or

```
php artisan db:seed --class=UsersTableSeeder
```

I hope will help someone.
PS: this was done on Laravel 5.3

Comment: Just used this in `Laravel v5.6.17`. Thanks!

Comment: @Casper thanks, it's useful to know it works in new Laravel version too :)

Comment: Wouldnt it be even better to not always insert a standard user with a standard password? Say im writing open source software this would be a security risk because lots of users wouldnt change it. Il provide a new answer as I have it.

Comment: @martin-eckleben, I think it's better to insert the hashed password, don't you think? "$2y$10$KZ4JiywQx2e0AMd.RWBd.ONSUcfsE1Jj0dYURgGq0BIwigMAQEYuK"

Comment: @Eleazar Resendez hmm better but still not good for the same argument.
lets say I write open source that other people are simply using and use a standard pw -> probably nobody would notice / change that and a lot of systems would be attackable with a standard pw. I think for security standard pws are always a bad approach. look at all the attackable devices / routers / firewalls etc. with standard pws.

Comment: @MartinEckleben sure, you should insert hashed passwords :) this was just a quick demo

Comment: @EleazarResendez this demo is not for production :)

Answer (score 17):

For password, open root of your project in terminal.

Then run `php artisan tinker;`

Then `echo Hash::make('password');`

Answer (score 15):

Place the following values in the `.env` file.

`INITIAL_USER_PASSWORDHASH` is **bcrypt** and has to be generated by the users.

You can use https://bcrypt-generator.com/ as a online generator tool to create passwords outside of the application.

Your application should provide an easier way.

You don't want to save *cleartext* passwords in the `env` file.

```
INITIAL_USER_NAME=
INITIAL_USER_EMAIL=
INITIAL_USER_PASSWORDHASH=
```

Then as suggested in the other answers before use a seeder:

To generate a seeder with `composer` you will need to use the following `artiasn` command.

`php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder`

This command will create a seeder file located in your `database/seeds` folder.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
  /**
   * Run the database seeds.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function run()
  {
    DB::table('users')->insert([
      'name' => env('INITIAL_USER_NAME'),
      'email' => env('INITIAL_USER_EMAIL'),
      'password' => env('INITIAL_USER_PASSWORDHASH'),
    ]);
  }
}
```

You will need to edit your `database/seeds/DatabaseSeeder.php` and make sure `UsersTableSeeder::class` is uncommitted inside the method `run()`.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
      $this->call([
        UsersTableSeeder::class
      ]);
    }
}
```

It is recommended you run the `composer dump-autoload` command after saving your changes.

You can run all seeds that are inside the `DatabaseSeeder.php` file by running the `artisan` command;

`php artisan db:seed`

You can alternatively use the following to execute only the one seeder by doing the `php artisan db:seed --class="UsersTableSeeder"` command.

You can also use `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` to do a fresh migration of your database tables and seed the table in a single command.

Comment: To create the `INITIAL_USER_PASSWORDHASH`, see @despotbg answer.

Answer (score 13):

Using php artisan tinker tool we could add a new user directly to data base.

```
$user = new App\User();
$user->password = Hash::make('password here ');
$user->email = 'proposed email@addresss.com';
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 10):

If you're concerned about saving a user's password insecurely in a text format to a repository or your server I suggest creating a command to create users for you.

See Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#generating-commands

In the handle method add something like this:

```
public function handle()
{
    $first_name = $this->ask('What is the first name?');
    $last_name = $this->ask('What is the last name?');
    $email = $this->ask('What is the email address?');
    $password = $this->secret('What is the password?');

    AdminUser::create([
        'first_name' => $first_name,
        'last_name' => $last_name,
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => bcrypt($password)
    ]);

    $this->info("User $first_name $last_name was created");
}
```

You are then able to run the command from the server and you haven't stored anything in a text based format!

Answer (score 3):

The most reasonable way is using DatabaseSeeder for such action.

I'll use example directly from documentation:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $this->call('UserTableSeeder');

        $this->command->info('User table seeded!');
    }

}

class UserTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->delete();

        User::create(array('login' => 'admin', 'password' => Hash::make('secret')));
    }
}
```

After creating such seeder, after `php artisan migrate` you can run `php artisan db:seed` and your 1st user will be created

Reference: [Database seeding in Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations#database-seeding)

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.6.39, I am doing following:

```
$user = new App\User();
$user->name = 'dhrubo';       //write whatever name you want
$user->password = Hash::make('dhrubo');    // write the password you want
$user->email = 'dhrubo@gmail.com';        // write the email you want
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Open root of your project in terminal.

If it is in Docker, enter in container (`docker exec -it <container_name> bash`).

Then run `php artisan tinker`

Then paste following line (one line):

```php
DB::table('users')->insert(['name' => ‘admin’, 'email' => ‘admin@email.com', 'password' => Hash::make('Admin@123'),]);
```

The login credentials will be:

- name : admin
- email: admin@email.com
- password: Admin@123

PS: if you do not have `tinker` installed, run `composer require laravel/tinker` command in the root of your project (in container, as stated above).